# Malware in the chat archive: wat do?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

My browser's security function is reporting that a segment of the chat archive has malware inserted into it. What could/should I do as an RPG.SE citizen?

Comment: I have no idea how to tag this. Any assistance in that regard would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: @balpha [Right here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=7414809#7414809)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an image in one of the chat messages that was hosted on a domain that Chrome flags as a possible malware distributor. The image was now a "404 not found" image anyway, so I've just deleted that message. The image filename was "doublefacepalm21.jpg", so I can [imagine](https://www.google.com/search?q=double+facepalm&tbm=isch) what it originally contained :)

As soon as I deleted the message, Chrome stopped flagging the page.

As to your question what you should do: Precisely what you did – post here on meta (or on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Thanks!